# c# Инспекция кода - Формирование строки с параметрами компьютера, используя Task

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Всем привет. Можно ли как-то чуть красивее оформить вызов задач (может даже быстрее, но я, пока что, не знаю, как это ещё быстрее сделать...)?

Суть задачи: Есть несколько методов, каждый из который выполняется за N времени (какой-то быстрее, какой-то чуть медленнее). Для оптимизации кода было решено выполнить данные методы в разных потоках. Таким образом получился следующий код:

```
Task task1 = new Task(CPU_ID);
task1.Start();
Task task2 = new Task(BIOS_ID);
task2.Start();
Task task3 = new Task(BaseBoardID);
task3.Start();
Task task4 = new Task(DiskDriveID);
task4.Start();
Task task5 = new Task(VideoControllerID);
task5.Start();
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task4, task5);
task1.Dispose();
task2.Dispose();
task3.Dispose();
task4.Dispose();
task5.Dispose();
    
HWID = HWIDClass.CPU + HWIDClass.BIOS + HWIDClass.BaseBoard + HWIDClass.DiskDrive + HWIDClass.VideoController;
```

Мне не очень нравится визуально такой кусок кода, где куча повторений. Можно ли это как-то свернуть (может в цикл или как-нибудь так)?

P.S. Результат работы каждого метода - передача в 'HWIDClass' переменной типа string

UPD:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HWIDVerification
{
    public class CerialNumberAsync
    {
        private static class HWIDClass
        {
            public static string CPU { get; set; }
            public static string BIOS { get; set; }
            public static string BaseBoard { get; set; }
            public static string DiskDrive { get; set; }
            public static string VideoController { get; set; }
        }

        public string HWID { get; private set; }
        public string HWIDHash { get; private set; }

        public CerialNumberAsync()
        {
            Value();
        }

        private void Value()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Empty))
            {
                Task task1 = new Task(CPU_ID);
                task1.Start();
                Task task2 = new Task(BIOS_ID);
                task2.Start();
                Task task3 = new Task(BaseBoardID);
                task3.Start();
                Task task4 = new Task(DiskDriveID);
                task4.Start();
                Task task5 = new Task(VideoControllerID);
                task5.Start();
                Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task4, task5);
                task1.Dispose();
                task2.Dispose();
                task3.Dispose();
                task4.Dispose();
                task5.Dispose();

                HWID = HWIDClass.CPU + HWIDClass.BIOS + HWIDClass.BaseBoard + HWIDClass.DiskDrive + HWIDClass.VideoController;

                HWIDHash = HashClass.GetHash(HWID);
            }
        }
        #region Original Device ID Getting Code
        private static string identifier (string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue)
        {
            string result = "";
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = new ManagementClass(wmiClass).GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (mo[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString() == "True")
                {
                    if (result == "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
        {
            string result = "";
            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(wmiClass);
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (result == "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static string TryGetString(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
        {
            try 
            {
                string result = $"{wmiProperty}: " + identifier(wmiClass, wmiProperty);
                return result + "\n";
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }

        private static void CPU_ID()
        {
            string result = TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "Name");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed");
            HWIDClass.CPU = "CPU >> " + result;
        }
        private static void BIOS_ID()
        {
            string result = TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
            HWIDClass.BIOS = "BIOS >> " + result;
        }
        private static void BaseBoardID()
        {
            string result = TryGetString("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer");
            HWIDClass.BaseBoard = "BaseBoard >> " + result;
        }
        private static void DiskDriveID()
        {
            string result = TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "SerialNumber");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model");
            HWIDClass.DiskDrive = "DiskDrive >> " + result;
        }
        private static void VideoControllerID()
        {
            string result = TryGetString("Win32_VideoController", "PNPDeviceID");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
            result += TryGetString("Win32_VideoController", "AdapterRAM");
            HWIDClass.VideoController = "VideoController >> " + result;
        }
        private static string MAC_ID()
        {
            try { return identifier("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration", "MACAddress", "IPEnabled"); }
            catch { return null; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Взаимодействие с классом такое:

Создаём экземпляр класса: `CerialNumberAsync cerialHash = new CerialNumberAsync();`
Далее, просто получаем из данного объекта строковую переменную HWIDHash: `cerialHash.HWIDHash`

Comment: Напишите в заголовке суть задачи, что этот код делает? Не пишите бессмысленных заголовков, иначе весь SO будет с одинаковыми. Покажите вызываемые методы, покажите структуру данных, которая здесь используется. Иначе нормального код-ревью не получится. Проблем здесь, само собой больше, чем вы видите.

Comment: 1) Поместить все задачи в массив. 2) В цикле их стартовать. 3) После цикла вызвать Task.WaitAll на массиве. 4) Вызывать Dispose на Task, вроде как, не обязательно

Comment: `HWID` - это string? Покажите код метода, где этот кусок целиком.

Comment: Прошу прощения за такой долгий ответ. Да, HWID - это строка

Comment: Прокомментрировал ваш ответ ниже и приложил к нему ссылку на данный класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что здесь не так - это использование конструкторов `Task`. Не используйте никогда конструктор `Task`, это устаревшее наследие, существующее для совместимости с древними дотнетами.

Конструкцию

```cs
Task task1 = new Task(CPU_ID);
task1.Start();
```

Можно и нужно преобразовать в:

```cs
Task task1 = Task.Run(CPU_ID);
```

Второе, что здесь не так, это баг, опечатка `task4, task4`.

Третье заключается в вызове `task1.Dispose();`. `Task` имплементирует `IDisposable`, а это значит, что внутри него есть `IDisposable` либо неуправляемые компоненты, и они есть. И этот компонент `task1.WaitHandle`, и создается он только в том случае, если вы хотя-бы один раз к нему обратились. В противном случае, а это 99,9% случаев использования, `Task` диспозить не нужно.

Вот и получается -10 строк.

```cs
Task task1 = Task.Run(CPU_ID);
Task task2 = Task.Run(BIOS_ID);
Task task3 = Task.Run(BaseBoardID);
Task task4 = Task.Run(DiskDriveID);
Task task5 = Task.Run(VideoControllerID);
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5);
    
HWID = HWIDClass.CPU + HWIDClass.BIOS + HWIDClass.BaseBoard + HWIDClass.DiskDrive + HWIDClass.VideoController;
```

И это еще только начало.

Далее, именования `CerialNumberAsync`, здесь `Cerial` наверное `Serial` и почему `Async`? Здесь нет даже намека на асинхронность и суффикс `Async` дописывают обычно методам, а не классам. Переименуйте например в `HWIDExtractor`. Будет понятно, что он "извлекает" `HWID`.

Имена методов. По конвенции Microsoft предложено аббревиатуры длинной более 2 символов писать просто с большой буквы, а не большими буквами. Например `BIOS` => `Bios`, сами же названия методов писать используя Camel Case, без подчеркиваний.

Разделяемые ресурсы. В многопоточной среде надо избегать использования разделяемых ресурсов настолько, насколько это возможно. Пусть даже у вас здесь выглядит безопасно, лучше убрать общий класс `HWIDClass`, без него здесь очень просто можно обойтись.

Чтобы обойтись без лишней структуры данных, можно результат работы возвращать из методов через возвращаемое значение, а не через разделяемый ресурс.

Кстати, `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Empty))` это всегда true, наверное вы имели в виду `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HWID))`? И это проверка здесь бессмысленная, потому что метод приватный и вызывается только из конструктора, то есть ровно один раз, не больше.

Применим к вызываемым методам предложенные изменения.

```cs
private static string CpuID()
{
    string result = TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "Name");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed");
    return "CPU >> " + result;
}

private static string BiosID()
{
    string result = TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
    return "BIOS >> " + result;
}

private static string BaseBoardID()
{
    string result = TryGetString("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer");
    return "BaseBoard >> " + result;
}

private static string DiskDriveID()
{
    string result = TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "SerialNumber");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model");
    return "DiskDrive >> " + result;
}

private static string VideoControllerID()
{
    string result = TryGetString("Win32_VideoController", "PNPDeviceID");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
    result += TryGetString("Win32_VideoController", "AdapterRAM");
    return "VideoController >> " + result;
}
```

Далее метод `Value`, почему `Value`? `GetHWID` было бы лучше, и так же через возвращаемое значение.

Далее, так как есть теперь 5 возвращаемых строк, можно пробросить их через таски, объединю методы в массив делегатов. Тогда на помощь придет всемогущий Linq.

```cs
private string GetHWID()
{
    Func<string>[] methods = new[] { CpuID, BiosID, BaseBoardID, DiskDriveID, VideoControllerID };
    return string.Concat(Task.WhenAll(methods.Select(Task.Run)).Result);
}
```

Теперь оно будет выглядеть так, что свойства инициализируются в конструкторе, как и должны. Код легче читать.

```cs
public HWIDExtractor()
{
    HWID = GetHWID();
    HWIDHash = HashClass.GetHash(HWID);
}
```

Кстати, почему если я BIOS пишу `Bios`, а `HWID` большими буквами, а потому что BIOS - это аббревиатура 4 слов, а HWID не аббревиатура, а сокращение двух слов, или 2 двухбуквенные аббревиатуры, и если бы я подчинялся правилам майкрософта, то выглядело бы так `HwId` - Hardware Identifier. Поэтому я каждое сокращаю до двух букв и получается, что 2 буквы пишем большими буквами - `HW` и `ID`.

И вишенка на торте, теперь, когда свойства присваиваются только в конструкторе - можно выкинуть сеттеры.

```cs
public string HWID { get; }
public string HWIDHash { get; }
```

Напоследок увидел еще странный метод

```cs
private static string TryGetString(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
{
    try 
    {
        string result = $"{wmiProperty}: " + identifier(wmiClass, wmiProperty);
        return result + "\n";
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Я не уверен, что `identifier` вообще может бросить исключение, есть ли смысл заворачивать его в `try-catch`? Но если не рисковать, и оставить как есть, то гораздо аккуратнее получится вот так.

```cs
return $"{wmiProperty}: {identifier(wmiClass, wmiProperty)}\n";
```

А то намешано конкатенации с интерполяцией. Старайтесь писать однотиным образом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. Загрузил данный класс на github. Вот ссылка: https://github.com/Frehzy/HWID/blob/main/HWIDVerification/CerialNumberAsync.cs. Думаю, здесь никак больше не получится ускорить выполнение метода 'Value()'

Comment: @Frehzy запостите весь код класса прямо в вопрос. Я не могу писать ревью для кода по ссылке.

Comment: Создал ответ на свой же вопрос и сделал его общим

Comment: @Frehzy общим не надо делать, просто запостите код в вопрос. Желательно до изменений, которые я предложил.

Comment: Не ожидал, что настолько много мелких ошибок у меня в коде. Единственный вопрос, который у меня возник - касаемо метода GetHWID. Я раньше особо не работал с функциями, поэтому не знаю, как избавиться от ошибки во 2 строке: https://pastenow.ru/F8D9K

Comment: @Frehzy WaitAll оказывается не умеет выплевывать результаты как мне нужно, исправил. Получилось грязновато, в плане того что по-хорошему метод GetHWID должен быть асинхронным, но при вызове из конструктора в этом мало смысла.

Comment: Да, я тоже сначала хотел попробовать Result, но не было его. Спасибо, ещё раз, за такой подробный ответ. Касаемо свойств, я просто привык писать в сеттерами, т.к. частенько код дописываю. Я так понимаю, мне нужно серьёзно пересмотреть своё оформление кода, т.к. частенько пренебрегаю "паттернами" его оформления. Обязательно перечитаю на сайте майкрософт об этом. p.s. даже не знаю, как я не заметил то, что класс у меня называется Cerial :D

Comment: @Frehzy оно хоть работает теперь? xD Кстати, ускорить это все-таки есть возможность. Но делать это надо в объединении запросов к WMI. Быть может стоит отдельно задать новый вопрос, если хотите, показать там получившийся код. С целью именно узнать как ускорить и можно  ли ускорить. К сожалению я WMI плохо знаю, но наверняка здесь есть умельцы, которые раскусят этот орех. У вас здесь 20 запросов к WMI, мне кажется, поэтому и медленно.